# How to aggregarte(make in Group) Enum constants with Amount

Tags: java

I have a enumeration which contains a large list of constants.I am showing here two constant data.

```
public enum PaymentType implements BaseEnum{
CASH(1, "Cash", "PaymentType.cash"),
CREDIT(2, "Credit Card", "PaymentType.credit");
```

Now I have a Payment Array. Payment array has PaymentTypes. So I am trying to aggregarte PaymentType using Amount. Grouping PaymentType with Amount. I used below code and it is working. But I have a large list of constants so i do not want to write hardcoded. can we have a logic which will aggregarte them.

```
for(Payment pay:payments){

        if(pay.getType().getCode() == PaymentType.CASH.getCode()){
            totalCash += payment.getAmount();
        } else
            if(pay.getType().getCode() == PaymentType.CREDIT.getCode()){
                totalCredit += payment.getAmount();
            }
    }
```

Output:-

```
 Cash $500
 Credit $1000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a arbitrary number of groupings, use a `Map`. In your case, the keys are enums, so use an `EnumMap`.

I'll assume that amount is a `BigDecimal`, since `double` is a bad choice for currency values (precision/rounding issues).

```
EnumMap<PaymentType, BigDecimal> totals = new EnumMap<>(PaymentType.class);
for (Payment payment : payments) {
    BigDecimal total = totals.get(payment.getType());
    total = (total == null ? payment.getAmount() : total.add(payment.getAmount()));
    totals.put(payment.getType(), total);
}
```

You can now get the total for any enum:

```
BigDecimal cashTotal = totals.get(PaymentType.CASH);
```

Value will be `null` if no payments of that type was found. If you want a zero value, use:

```
// Any Java version
BigDecimal cashTotal = totals.get(PaymentType.CASH);
if (cashTotal == null)
    cashTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;

// Java 8+
BigDecimal cashTotal = totals.getOrDefault(PaymentType.CASH, BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

**Update**

Using `double` is very similar:

```
// Summarize
EnumMap<PaymentType, Double> totals = new EnumMap<>(PaymentType.class);
for (Payment payment : payments) {
    Double total = totals.get(payment.getType());
    total = (total == null ? payment.getAmount() : total.doubleValue() + payment.getAmount());
    totals.put(payment.getType(), total);
}

// Without autoboxing
    total = Double.valueOf(total == null ? payment.getAmount() : total.doubleValue() + payment.getAmount());

// Get total
Double totalObj = totals.get(PaymentType.CASH);
double cashTotal = (totalObj != null ? totalObj.doubleValue() : 0d);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks correct. I am not able to use BigDecimal because code is old and if i will change, there will be a lot of changes as well models etc. may we use double?